# Can we use RobotFramework to automate MacOsx application?

Tags: macos, appium, robotframework

Can we use RobotFramework to automate MacOSx application?
I could not find any documentation on this. Can you share some example on this.

Comment: try appium for mac and see if it fills your needs.

Comment: Yes, I used Appium

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead with Appium. It is working fine for me so far.